# Angular Material Mat Stepper: Is it possible to have multiple steps being active/shown?

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-stepper

Is it possible to have multiple steps opened/being displayed on Angular Mat Stepper?

I can only show one, and I've been trying to look for an answer, but I didn't see anything about it.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It it not possible to show more than one step at the time. This is because, as explained by the documentation [here](https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/overview), its intended use case is to provide a wizard-like workflow by dividing content into logical steps.

For your use case I will recommend you to use the [Expansion Panel](https://material.angular.io/components/expansion/overview) instead, as it is possible to show multiple expansions at the same time as shown in this example [here](https://material.angular.io/components/expansion/examples#expansion-expand-collapse-all).